# bind iframe src data-win-bind

Tags: javascript, data-binding, microsoft-metro

I am attempting to bind a value to the src attribute of an iFrame in a windows 8 metro app, javascript.

the error is Value is not supported within a declarative processing context, if you want it to be supported mark it using WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed for security reasons.

You can, however, create a custom binding function:

```
var ponies = WinJS.Binding.initializer(function (x, y, z) {
    z.src = WinJS.Utilities.getMember(y.join('.'), x);
});
```

Then, for your iframe:

```
<iframe data-win-bind="src:url ponies"></iframe>
```